# Get resource ID from class member CEdit, MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, cedit

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to create a MFC application. I've created a simple dialog with the help of the recource editor. The dialog contains a number of Edit Controls. I've added members to those Edit Controls by rightclicking on them - > Add Variable. Lets say I have an Edit Control with `ID = ID_EDB_NAME` and lets say `ID_EDB_NAME = 1111` for this example.I have added a variable `CEdit m_edbName`. Is there any method that I can call from `m_edbName` that returns `1111`?

Comment: You are probably looking for the [`GetDlgCtrlID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1shyeyy5.aspx) function

Comment: The resource file format does not allow you to create a resource of type Edit Control. Hence, your Edit Control doesn't have a resource ID (the parent dialog does, though). You are looking for the **control** ID, and the comment by @MichaelWalz explained, how to retrieve it.

Comment: @IInspectable I didn't quite get your statement _The resource file format does not allow you to create a resource of type Edit Control_. I'm doing this all the time.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: These are the [predefined resource types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648009.aspx). As you can see, there isn't one for (edit) controls, or even generic windows. An [EDITTEXT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381009.aspx) resource-definition statement can only appear inside a container, not as a top-level resource-definition statement. Only top-level resources have resource IDs.

Comment: @IInspectable OK, I just misunderstood your comment.